# Write recursive data in excel from python list

Tags: python, excel, list, for-loop, xlwt

I have a list of webpages called: `html`

in each and every `html(i)` element I extracted emails addresses. I put these emails addresses in the list: `email`

I want to  generate an excel file like this:

[image]

in order to write down on an excel file all the emails addresses I found.

Since each `html(i)` page may contain a different number of emails addresses, I would like to write a code to take into account the different number of emails found per page, automatically.

My idea was something similar to this:

```
#set the standard url to generate the full list of urls to be analyzed
 url = ["url1","url2", "url3", "url-n"]

#get all the url pages' html codes
 for i in range (0,len(url):
     html=[urllib.urlopen(url[i]).read() for i in range(0,len(url)) ]

#find all the emails in each html page. 
 for i in range (0,len(url):
     emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', html[i])

#create an excel file
 wb = Workbook()

#Set the excel file. 
 for i in range (0,len(html)):
     for j in range (0, len(emails)):
         sheet1.write(i, j, emails[j])

wb.save('emails contact2.xls')
```

Of course is not working. It only writes the email addresses contained in the last element of list html. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the `emails` list you describe is. Is it a nested list of some kind? If not, you probably need to generate it inside your outer loop (rather than ahead of time).

Comment: 1 list `emails` does not make any sense.. How can you separate the emails for each `html`? Do you have a list for each `html`? Maybe you want to use a `dict`?

Comment: I modified the code, pasting what I'm working on. I hope it's more clear for you guys. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlwt
wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

htmls = generate_htmls() #Imaginary function to pretend it's initialized.
for i in xrange(len(htmls)):
    sheet1.write(i, 0, htmls[i])
    emails = extract_emails(htmls[i]) #Imaginary function to pretend it's extracted
    for j in xrange(len(emails)):
        sheet1.write(i, j + 1, emails[i])
```

Assuming you extract the list `emails` for each html separately, this code puts the html in the 1st (index 0) column, then puts all the emails in the `index + 1` (to not overwrite the first column).

Comment: @GiacomoBonvini Thanks for marking my answer as correct. But I have a question for you - do you understand why it works? Because I don't want people to just copy paste my answers, I want people to learn from them. Did you understand, or should I add some more explanation?

Comment: thanks for your thought. I think I have understood how it works. It writes row by row fixing the html in the first column and then writing the emails in the other columns. Correct? Of course if you have any other comments are more than welcome. I started programming in python 3 days ago eheh

Comment: Glad you got it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about xlwt but considering you have a list of `emails` for each `html` would something like this work?

```
 import xlwt
 wb = Workbook()

 for html_index, html in enumerate(html):
     sheet1.write(html_index, 0, html.address)
     for email_index, email in enumerate(emails_for_html):
          sheet1.write(html_index, email_index + 1, email)

 wb.save('email contacts.xls')
```

*Please note that I don't know xlwt specific commands, just trying to imitate yours.*

Comment: `enumerate` is 0 based, so writing in the `email_index` will overwrite the html in the first column.. It should be `email_index + 1` :-)

Comment: Thanks for editing! Also, the option of `enumerate(email_for_html, 1)` (providing a starting value of 1) is also possible ;-)